# Do voltage-limiting resistors exist?

Tags: resistors

I see sometimes that resistors are specified as current-limiting resistors, so I decided to see if voltage-limiting ones exist. When I do a search though, I don't see anything mentioning voltage-limiting resistors.

Comment: "current-limiting" is not a type of a resistor, it is a function of the resistor in a particular circuit.

Comment: I can imagine circuits where a resistor would limit voltage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A voltage source is theoretically capable of supplying an infinite current into a short circuit hence if a series resistor is used then that short circuit current becomes amps or milliamps rather than infinite amps.

A current source, on the other hand, will not be affected by a series resistor at all - it will continue to produce whatever voltage is needed into an "open circuit" resorting to making a sustained electrical arc to create a conductive path if necessary. In these circumstances a parallel resistor will restrict the open circuit voltage because it will conduct the current back to the other terminal of the current source.

So, in short, a resistor can be a voltage limiting AND a current limiting device.

> I see sometimes that resistors are specified as current-limiting
>   resistors

They are not specified as such i.e. a resistor isn't to be regarded as a current limiting resistor rather, it is the function it plays in the target circuit that may be described as "current limiting".

Answer (score 0):

Example of Resistor used as current limiter and voltage divider (limiter)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu0vZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you mean a polyfuse , then there is no voltage limiting R.

These have a large PTC ( positive tempco.) that rises in R exponentially past the holding current, causing a  rapid rise in junction temperature from 120 to 140’C where current is limited by a design limit. These have a cold (25’C) resistance rating as well.

The opposite temperature characteristic is a large NTC which drops in R rapidly as it heats up.  These are used as inrush current limiters called ICL’s and also have a cold and hot resistance ratings with corresponding current ratings.

Both are metal oxide components but with a different mix of conductive particles in a ceramic composition.

Voltage limiters are semiconductive such as; TVS, MOV, Zeners and diodes.  These cannot substitute as a fixed R value but do have some high leakage resistance that changes with many factors such as temperature.